# assign from a const reference vs std::move()

Tags: c++11

Given the following snippet, what happens in each case (w.r.t. copying):

```
std::string GetString() {
 return "my string";
}

class MyObj {
...
std::string* mutable_str(); 
...
};

// 1) Assigning the value hold by reference 'a', makes a copy.
const std::string& a = GetString(); 
*Obj.mutable_str() = a

// 2) Not a copy, 'b' is a temporary. 
std::string b = GetString(); 
*Obj.mutable_str() = std::move(b);
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Assigning the value hold by reference 'a', makes a copy.

Correct

> 2. Not a copy, `b` is a temporary.

Partly wrong. `b` is an ordinary object who's value was materialised from the temporary returned by `GetString`. There is no copy, instead it's contents were *moved* into `*Obj.mutable_str()`, leaving `b` in a valid but unspecified state.